# How to conditionally import a few dependencies?

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api

I am facing a peculiar issue.
Our app used to use the fingerprint sdk from Samsung for fingerprint authentication.
Now from android M android came out with its fingerprint API's. So we moved to android libraries for all devices >= android M.
However for samsung devices < Android.M we still use the mpass sdk for legacy compatibility.
In one of the classes we import the below:

```
import com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassInvalidStateException;
```

Now this causes issues on all non-samsung devices and we get the below exception:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.SpassFingerprint$b>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/samsung/android/fingerprint/IFingerprintClient$Stub;

Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class: java.lang.Class<com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.b>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/samsung/android/fingerprint/FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener;
```

I understand this is because the samsung libraries are not present on non samsung phones.
My question is how do I conditionally import the Samsung dependencies so that I don't see this issue in non Samsung devices

Comment: You first need to get project configuration and then 
 try this code configuration.getDependencies().add(dependenyMock);

Comment: you need to use reflection